Proposition 6.2.3 from Goss "Basic Structures of Function Field Arithmetic"
I'm studying Proposition 6.2.3 from Goss "Basic Structures of Function Field Arithmetic", page 184:
Let $F$ be the sheaf of Data A (a torsion-free coherent $O_{\bar{X}}$-module on $\bar{X}$ and a maximal flag of coherent sub-$O_{\bar{X}}$-modules $F_n \subset F_{n+1}$ with lenght($F_{n+1}/F_n$)=1) except that we assume $\chi (F)=0$. Then $h^1(F)=h^2(F)=0$.
In the proof we choose $n_0$ be the smallest $n$ such that $h^0(F_n) \neq 0$ and let $0\neq s_0 \in H^0(\bar{X},F_{n_0})$ and then consider the $O_{\bar{X}}$-module homomorphisms
\begin{gather*}
\alpha: \tilde{\sigma}^{*}F_n \longrightarrow F_{n+1},
\end{gather*}
such that $\alpha$ takes $\sigma^*F_n$ to $F_{n+1}$; and define inductively sections $s_n \in H^0(\bar{X},F_{n+n_0})$ by $s_n:= \alpha(\tilde{\sigma}^*s_{n-1})$. Then he says that, since $\chi({F_{n+1}})=\chi({{\sigma}^*F_n})+1$ then the length of cokernel of $\alpha$ must be 1 and, as $\alpha$ is assumed not to be surjective on $\bar{X}-P$, we conclude that it must be surjertive at $P$ ($P$ a closed point). Then he concludes with the equality
\begin{gather*}
F_{n+1}=F_n+\alpha(\sigma^*F_n).
\end{gather*}
Why is that (length of $\alpha$, surjectivity and equality) so? Moreover, is it possible that $\alpha$ is the homomorphism 0?
Could anyone explain me please?
